# Search through magento admin panel to see which script are loaded where

Tags: magento2, google-tag-manager

I am using magento2.3.5-p2 Community Edition

I am having a problem on finding the location of certain code,

I have tried templatehints, search using grep and find all contents in file but to no avail the code still not able to be find

The code below, the highlighted one is the one I am trying to find the location of that

[image]

When I inspect element the page, the code is not hovering to any element, the nearest element is the footer but I am unsure, do take a look at image below

[image]

[image]

When I hover into the

`<div class="debugging-hints"` that is which is the nearest to the `<noscript><iframe src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/ns.html?id=GTM-GE2HRWD" height="0" width="0" style="display:none;visibility:hidden"></iframe></noscript>`
only then I will get the source file which is at

`/var/www/html/myecommerceproject/app/code/MageBig/QuickView/view/frontend/templates/quickview.popup.phtml`

but even then. When I check on the source code for the intended script I want to find it does not exists, It must be somewhere in the configuration of Magento admin panel, but I am not sure where

Any help is kindly appreciated, thank you

Answer (score 1):

Simply you can use **grep** command for search in file through SSH

```
grep -l -r "your string" foldername/
```

> e.g grep -l -r "www.googletagmanager.com/" vendor/magento
>
> e.g grep -l -r "www.googletagmanager.com/" app/

Comment: Hi, i have searched and there is no file which contains text of 'googletagmanager' or related to it, I think this value are not coming from the source code

Comment: I think it's must be coming from source code but if not then please search in database too

Answer (score 0):

within magento root folder, do a

`grep -R '<!-- GOOGLE TAG MANAGER -->' vendor/magento/module-*`

and you can look at all the templates using this code

Comment: Hi, i have searched and there is no file which contains text of 'googletagmanager' or related to it, I think this value are not coming from the source code

Comment: You ok community version or enterprise ?

Comment: Look for ga.phtml file in vendor

Comment: I am using community edition

Comment: owh finally found some trace of google api here, but its google analytics vendor/magento/module-google-analytics/view/frontend/layout/default.xml

Comment: Oh, well I just noticed that `(noscript)` is in comment which is different from what we have on other ga.phtml files. 

It may be coming from other third party module or may be database.

Just do grep -R '(noscript)' * in root to see if you find any file. (or may be exact line from comment.)

Or worst case, check head section in design config for theme or check if core config table contains anything similar.